# how to make reactjs call Component from external file

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas

I want to make a react app to run this Component from external file  and i am not using any bundle in my app like webpack or etc... and also

React/app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import BounceCircle from './canvas';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header/>
        <Content/>
        <Footer/>
        <BounceCircle/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1>Hello World</h1>
          <h4>hello to egypt</h4>
          <h3>Welcome to React</h3>
          <h4>hi</h4>
        </div>

    );
  }
}

class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

            <p className="App-intro">
              To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
              </p>

    );
  }
}

class Footer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (    
          <h3>this the Footer</h3>

    );
  }
}






export default App;
```

and here it the Component code which i want it to be import and work in react app , basically is a html5 canvas i try to make it run in react app

canvas.js

```
class BounceCircle extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
            //this var = canvas is to call the canvas tag from html file using querySelector
             canvas=document.querySelector('canvas');
            //this makes the width of the canvas the full width the screen
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            //this makes the height of the canvas the full height the screen
            canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
            // this var = c is to call var canvas to start to work on it 
            var c=canvas.getContext("2d");


            var mouse = {
                x:undefined,
                y:undefined
            }

            var maxRadius = 40;
            var colorArray=[
                '#FF595E',
                '#33032F',
                '#313E50',
                '#0E7C7B',
                '#87BCDE',
            ];
            window.addEventListener('mousemove',
                function(event){
                    mouse.x=event.x;
                    mouse.y=event.y;
            })

            window.addEventListener('resize',function()
            {
                //this makes the width of the canvas the full width the screen
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            //this makes the height of the canvas the full height the screen
                canvas.height=window.innerHeight;

                init(); 
            })
            function Circle(x,y,dx,dy,radius){
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.dx= dx;
                this.dy= dy;
                this.radius=radius;
                this.minRadius=radius;
                this.color=colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length)];
                this.draw = function()
                {

                    c.beginPath();
                    c.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI * 2,false);
                    c.fillStyle=this.color;
                    c.strokeStyle=this.color;
                    c.fill();
                }
                this.update = function(){
                    if (this.x + this.radius> innerWidth || this.x-this.radius < 0 ) {
                this.dx = -this.dx ;
            }

            if (this.y + this.radius> innerHeight || this.y-this.radius < 0 ) {
                this.dy = -this.dy ;
            }
                this.x += this.dx;
                this.y += this.dy;

                //interactivity
                if (mouse.x - this.x <50 && mouse.x-this.x>-50 && mouse.y - this.y <50 && mouse.y-this.y>-50 ) {
                    if (this.radius<maxRadius) {
                        this.radius+= 1;
                    }

                } else if (this.radius>this.minRadius) {
                    this.radius-= 1;
                }
                this.draw();
                }
            }


            var circleArray=[];
                for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
             {
                var radius=Math.random() * 3 + 1;
                var x =Math.random()*innerWidth;
                var y = Math.random()*innerHeight;
                var dx= (Math.random() - 0.5)*16;
                var dy= (Math.random() - 0.5)*16;


                circleArray.push(new Circle(x,y,dx,dy,radius));

            }

            function init()
            {
             circleArray=[];

            }


            function animate(){
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                c.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight);

            for (var i = 0; i < circleArray.length; i++) 
            {
                circleArray[i].update();
            }

            }

            animate();



    );
  }
}

export default BounceCircle;
```

the both files is in the same folder

Comment: `import App from "./app.js"`? Please be more precise about what you tried and what didn't work

Comment: @Damien Leroux 3 , no i want to do the opposite i want to import from the canvas.js to the app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `app.js` you can say:

```
import BounceCircle from './canvas'
```

And then you can use it like any other component `<BounceCircle />`

Import from external files are like imports from node_modules. Just point to the right directory.

In the file you can see there's a `default export`. You can name `default exports` as you like in your `app.js`. So all these will work, and will return the same thing (BounceCircle):

```
import Cheese from './canvas';
import Canvas from './canvas';
import MyThingy from './canvas';
```

Other exports like:

```
`myCode.js`

export class Pies extends Component { /* code */ }

class Cake extends Component { /* code */ }

default export Cake;
```

Now we've got a default export for `Pies`, but we also have an `export class` (not a default)

Those not defaults can be imported by using curlies:

```
import { Pies } from './myCode'
```

The value in the curlies, should always match the name from the imported file.

But it would still be possible this, which result in the same thing:

```
import Cake, { Pies } from './myCode'
import ICanUseEverythingHere, { Pies } from './myCode'
```

Comment: here is the screen show now `Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/canvas.js
Syntax error: D:/My WebSites for Git/React App/my-app/src/canvas.js: Unexpected token (4:4)

  2 | 
  3 |      //this var = canvas is to call the canvas tag from html file using querySelector
> 4 | var canvas=document.querySelector('canvas');
    |     ^
  5 | //this makes the width of the canvas the full width the screen
  6 | canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  7 | //this makes the height of the canvas the full height the screen

 @ ./src/App.js 20:14-33`

Comment: That means the import was succesfull, but that the code you're trying to import contains some faults. Setting variables inside the return statement also isn't the behaviour of a React Component. The return statement of the `render()` should only contains dom nodes. You probably copied this code from somewhere? You should rewrite it, so it works for React.

Comment: You know what the code should do I hope. Just put it all outside the `render()` Only put in the `render()` the stuff that needs to be displayed.

Comment: the code is doing html5 canvas so i wanted to make a intro website using canvas in react

Comment: You might want to look at the `react-canvas` package then.

Comment: look it works in the same page with here is the proof https://codepen.io/HusseinZaki/pen/OOxewm i want only to make it work also from external file

Comment: The difference is that that Codepen doesn't include the canvas code inside a react component. You've just pasted it in globally. If you were to paste you're BouncingCircle code inside the HTML template, you'd probably get a working example too. But that isn't a `React` way of solving it.